# Is there a way a recycler view with GridLayout Vertically Scrolling, handle horizontal gestures

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I am making an Calendar app and i am using a RecyclerView to show the monthDays. I am beginner so i could't make the recycler view to scroll Horizontally and in every scroll change month like Google Calendar for example. So I made my Recycler View with my adaptor and I use a GridLayout with span:7 that scrolls Vertically and to change month I added two button (next month,previous month). My question is: Is there any way to keep my layout as it is and my Recycler view handle gestures from the user, so if the user trying to scroll to left change to previous month and if the user trying to scroll right change to next month. Some kind of Gesture handler to put my methods in there. I searched a lot and I didn't find anything suitable for my problem.

**My xml code for the RecyclerView, the monthListView doesn't matter, it is visibility:gone when in MonthView.**

```
 <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/daysOfWeek"
                >

                <ScrollView
                    android:id="@+id/scrolTest"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    >
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                            android:id="@+id/calendarRecyclerView"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:clipToPadding="true"
                            android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"
                            android:scrollbars="none"/>

                    </LinearLayout>
                </ScrollView>





                        <ListView
                            android:id="@+id/monthListView"
                            android:layout_width="@dimen/hour_cell_Lin_width"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                            android:dividerHeight="10dp"
                            android:scrollbars="vertical"
                            android:visibility="gone"
                            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"

                            android:layout_below="@id/scrolTest"/>


            </RelativeLayout>
```

**The way I set my RecyclerView.**

```
ArrayList<LocalDate> daysInMonth = daysInMonthArray();
  CalendarAdapter calendarAdapter = new CalendarAdapter(daysInMonth, this, getApplicationContext());
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(), 7);


        calendarRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

        calendarRecyclerView.setAdapter(calendarAdapter);
```

**The way i set up my CalendarMonthArray**

```
public static ArrayList<LocalDate> daysInMonthArray() //The arraylist that month will be stored
    {
        ArrayList<LocalDate> daysInMonthArray = new ArrayList<>();

        YearMonth yearMonth = null;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            yearMonth = YearMonth.from(selectedDate);
        }
        int daysInMonth = 0; //get how many days are in month
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            daysInMonth = yearMonth.lengthOfMonth();
        }

        LocalDate prevMonth = null;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            prevMonth = selectedDate.minusMonths(1);
        }
        LocalDate nextMonth = null;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            nextMonth = selectedDate.plusMonths(1);
        }

        YearMonth prevYearMonth = null;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            prevYearMonth = YearMonth.from(prevMonth);
        }
        int prevDaysInMonth = 0;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            prevDaysInMonth = prevYearMonth.lengthOfMonth();
        }

        LocalDate firstOfMonth = null; //get first day of month
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            firstOfMonth = CalendarUtils.selectedDate.withDayOfMonth(1);
        }
        int dayOfWeek = 0; // return int between 0-7 which is the day of the week
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            dayOfWeek = firstOfMonth.getDayOfWeek().getValue();
        }

        for (int i = 1; i <= 42; i++) {
            if (i <= dayOfWeek) {

                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                    daysInMonthArray.add(LocalDate.of(prevMonth.getYear(), prevMonth.getMonth(), prevDaysInMonth + i - dayOfWeek));
                }
                if (dayOfWeek == 7 && daysInMonthArray.size() >= 7) {

                    daysInMonthArray.clear();
                }


            } else if (i > daysInMonth + dayOfWeek) {

                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                    daysInMonthArray.add(LocalDate.of(nextMonth.getYear(), nextMonth.getMonth(), i - dayOfWeek - daysInMonth));
                }


            }
            else {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                    daysInMonthArray.add(LocalDate.of(selectedDate.getYear(), selectedDate.getMonth(), i - dayOfWeek));
                }

            }

        }


        return daysInMonthArray;


    }
```

Comment: Google Calendar is using ViewPager for horizontal scroll month change

Comment: Thank you for the reply, do you recommend to use this ViewPager or do you believe that I can modify my code for the question I made?

Comment: You can use nested recyclerview for this purpose, Top RV for months with Horizontal layout and nested recyclerview for month days with gridlayout

Comment: If i understand your recommendation, you mean to keep my RV with the days of month as it is and above of this, to put small RV horizontally so when i scroll it update my daysinMonthRecyclerView by the month in the top RV?

Comment: Parent RecyclerView( Horizontal -> Month1(Child RecyclerView(GridLayout -> days, week)), month2(Child RecyclerView(GridLayout -> days, week)) +)

Comment: I think I understand what you are saying, I will see how can I modify my code to this, and I will update the question,

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253715/discussion-between-chris-damianidis-and-abdullah-javed).